# Persisting State using Hydrated Bloc version 5 and above

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

<strike>I am trying to use Hydrated Bloc to persist the state in my app. The tutorials I have found are all using previous versions of Hydrated Blocs and use the `BlocSupervisor`, which was removed in the Dart version of the `bloc` package in v.5 (https://pub.dev/packages/bloc/changelog). `flutter_bloc` and `hydrated_bloc` removed it when they updated to `bloc` v.5 (https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc/changelog and https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc/changelog).
The documentation says it should be replaced with the `BlocObserver`. `hydrated_bloc` and `flutter_bloc` do not list a replacement. So far, I have not found a *HydratedBloc* tutorial that uses anything other than `BlocSupervisor` and `BlocDelegate`; only `flutter_bloc` tutorials.</strike>

How do I create the HydratedBloc equivalent of the `BlocObserver` in order to persist state?

EDIT:
Okay, I think I'm on the right track now thanks to your example.

Here is the relevant portion of my code, with the classes renamed:

```
class ClassABLoC
    extends HydratedBloc<ClassAEvent, ClassAState> {
//This does initialize it with some values, but not the ones from storage. Trying to call fromJson() there gives an error. 
 ClassABLoC() : super(ClassAState.dataNotReceived());
@override
  Stream<classAState> mapEventToState(
      classAEvent event) async* {

    if (event is classAInitialize){
      print("Initializing");
      yield fromJson(json.decode(
        HydratedBloc.storage.read("vehicleNumber") as String,
        ) as Map<String, dynamic>,
      );
    }

    if (event is classAValidate) {
      yield classAState.validated(
        theEvent: event,
        numberValidated: validateTheInput(event.numberVal, event.vehicleNumber),
        distanceValidated:
            validateTheInput(event.distanceVal, event.vehicleDistanceTraveled),
        yearValidated: validateTheInput(event.yearVal, event.vehicleYear),
        vinValidated: validateTheInput(event.vinVal, event.vin),
        licensePlateValidated:
            validateTheInput(event.licensePlateVal, event.vehicleLicensePlate),
        revsPerDistValidated:
            validateTheInput(event.revsPerDistVal, event.vehicleRevsPerDist),
        fuelTypeValidated: validateTheInput(event.fuelTypeVal, event.fuelType),
        fuelCapacityValidated:
            validateTheInput(event.fuelCapacityVal, event.fuelCapacity),
        siteValidated: validateTheInput(event.siteVal, event.vehicleSite),
        numberError: event.numberVal!.validationFailedMsg,
        distanceError: event.distanceVal!.validationFailedMsg,
        yearError: event.yearVal!.validationFailedMsg,
        vinError: event.vinVal!.validationFailedMsg,
        licensePlateError: event.licensePlateVal!.validationFailedMsg,
        revsPerDistError: event.revsPerDistVal!.validationFailedMsg,
        fuelTypeError: event.fuelTypeVal!.validationFailedMsg,
        fuelCapacityError: event.fuelCapacityVal!.validationFailedMsg,
        siteError: event.siteVal!.validationFailedMsg,
      );
    } else if (event is StoreDataEvent) {
      toJson(StoreDataState(
        vehicleNumber: event.vehicleNumber,
        vehicleYear: event.vehicleYear,
        vehicleRevsPerDist: event.vehicleRevsPerDist,
        vehicleDistanceTraveled: event.vehicleDistanceTraveled,
        vin: event.vin,
        vehicleLicensePlate: event.vehicleLicensePlate,
        fuelCapacity: event.fuelCapacity,
        fuelType: event.fuelType,
        vehicleSite: event.vehicleSite,
      ));
    }
  }

Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(ProgramDataTracSVTState state) {
    if (state is StoreDataState) {
      print("State was StoreDataState.");
      print(state.toString());
      return {
        'vehicleNumber': state.vehicleNumber,
        'vehicleDistanceTraveled': state.vehicleDistanceTraveled,
        'vehicleLicensePlate': state.vehicleLicensePlate,
        'vin': state.vin,
        'rehicleRevsPerDist': state.vehicleRevsPerDist,
        'vehicleSite': state.vehicleSite,
        'vehicleYear': state.vehicleYear,
        'fuelCapacity': state.fuelCapacity,
        'fuelType': state.fuelType,
        'distUnit': state.distUnits,
      };
    }
  }


ProgramDataTracSVTState fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    print(json['vehicleDistance'] as String);
    return ProgramDataTracSVTState(
      vehicleNumber: (json['vehicleNumber'] as String?) == "" ||
              json['vehicleNumber'] == null
          ? "HARDCODED"
          : json['vehicleNumber'] as String,
      vehicleDistanceTraveled:
          (json['vehicleDistanceTraveled'] as String?) == "" ||
                  (json['vehicleDistanceTraveled'] as String?) == null
              ? "HARDCODED VALUE"
              : json['vehicleDistanceTraveled'] as String,
      vehicleLicensePlate: (json['vehicleLicensePlate'] as String?) == "" ||
              (json['vehicleLicensePlate'] as String?) == null
          ? ""
          : json['vehicleLicensePlate'] as String,
      vin: (json['vin'] as String?) == "" || (json['vin'] as String?) == null
          ? "HARDCODED VALUE"
          : json['vin'] as String,
      vehicleRevsPerDist: (json['vehicleRevsPerDist'] as String?) == "" ||
              (json['vehicleRevsPerDist'] as String?) == null
          ? "500"
          : json['vehicleRevsPerDist'] as String,
      vehicleSite: (json['vehicleSite'] as String?) == "" ||
              (json['vehicleSite'] as String?) == null
          ? "Home Base Site"
          : (json['vehicleSite'] as String),
      vehicleYear: (json['vehicleYear'] as String?) == "" ||
              (json['vehicleYear'] as String?) == null
          ? "2018"
          : json['vehicleYear'] as String,
      fuelCapacity: (json['fuelCapacity'] as String?) == "" ||
              (json['fuelCapacity'] as String?) == null
          ? ""
          : (json['fuelCapacity'] as String),
      fuelType: (json['fuelType'] as String?) == "" ||
              (json['fuelType'] as String?) == null
          ? "Diesel"
          : (json['fuelType'] as String),
      distUnits: (json['distUnit'] as String?) == "" ||
              (json['distUnit'] as String?) == null
          ? "None"
          : (json['distUnit'] as String),
    );
  }
```

I need to get more than one string's worth of data from the storage. How would I do that? I can't combine the JSON strings as far as I know.

Comment: The examples provided here https://pub.dev/packages/hydrated_bloc/example are working examples of how to persist state. What type of data are you trying to persist?

Comment: @Loren.A, thanks! I am trying to persist text strings. The toJson method is set up correctly and will persist the state between hot reloads but not a restart.

Comment: You should have an override of `toJson` and `fromJson`. Can you share those? It should prompt you once you extend `HydratedBloc`.

Comment: Sorry, was already off for the weekend without access to the code when I saw this! Added the toJson and fromJson.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Update

So if I understand correctly you're looking for a full on database in addition to just being able to restart in whatever previous state you were in.

My original answer shows the latter. After looking at your code I should clarify that you don't need to manually call the `toJson` and `fromJson` methods. Those get called automatically any time the state changes and it overwrites whatever was stored previously, and on app restart will restore the most recent state.

So you're returning a `ProgramDataTracSVTState` in your `fromJson`. Wherever in the app that you're displaying that state of `ClassABLoC` on app restart, should display the last active state without you setting up a dedicated `classAInitialize` event just to manually call `fromJson`. See my first example for reference on that.

In order to store multiple instances of your `VehicleModel` for a typical local database (I assume you have a model class for what you're storing in your `toJson`, if not, you should create one), I would create separate methods that calls `HydratedBloc.storage.write(key, value)` and `HydratedBloc.storage.read(key)`to access whichever vehicle you need from storage.

If all your vehicle numbers are unique you could use that as a key to access any vehicle in the main storage map.

Here's a simplified example with a basic `CarModel`

```
class CarModel {
  final int id;
  final String car;

  CarModel({required this.id, required this.car});

  CarModel.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> map)
      : id = map['id'],
        car = map['car'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() {
    return {
      'id': id,
      'car': car,
    };
  }
}
```

`Events`

```
class PrintStorageData extends TestEvent {}

class StoreDataEvent extends TestEvent {
  final CarModel car;

  StoreDataEvent({required this.car});
}
```

`states`

```
abstract class TestState extends Equatable {
  final CarModel testModel;

  const TestState(this.testModel);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [testModel];
}

class State1 extends TestState {
  State1({required CarModel model}) : super(model);
}
```

Updated `TestBloc`

```
class TestBloc extends HydratedBloc<TestEvent, TestState> {
  TestBloc()
      : super(State1(model: CarModel(id: 0, car: 'no cars listed'))) {
    on<PrintStorageData>(
      (event, emit) => _printStorageData(),
    );

    on<StoreDataEvent>((event, emit) {
      emit(State1(model: event.car)); // toJson gets called here and fromJson on app restart

      _storeCarModel(event.car); // this is what stores in a database you can access later on
    });
  }

  Future<void> _printStorageData() async {
    final mapFromStorage =
        await HydratedBloc.storage.read('vehicles') as Map? ?? {};

    if (mapFromStorage.isNotEmpty) {
      mapFromStorage.forEach((key, value) {
        log('$key: $value');
      });
    } else {
      log('No vehicles stored');
    }
  }

  Future<void> _storeCarModel(CarModel model) async {
    final id = model.id; // using id for storage key
    final storageMap = await HydratedBloc.storage.read('vehicles') as Map? ??
        {}; // initializing to empty map if nothing is stored
    storageMap[id] = model.toJson();
    await HydratedBloc.storage.write('vehicles', storageMap);
  }

  @override
  TestState fromJson(Map<String, dynamic>? json) {
    return State1(model: CarModel.fromJson(json!));
  }

  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(TestState state) {
    return {'id': state.testModel.id, 'car': state.testModel.car};
  }
}
```

To check this you can add a few cars in the UI and print the stored list after restart

```
      ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.read<TestBloc>().add(PrintStorageData()),
              child: Text('Read Data'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                final car = CarModel(id: 1, car: 'tesla');
                context.read<TestBloc>().add(StoreDataEvent(car: car));
              },
              child: Text('Store new car'),
            ),
```

## Original Answer

Since you didn't provide any of your code here's an example of saving a basic `String`.

`State`

```
abstract class TestState extends Equatable {
  final String testString;

  const TestState(this.testString);

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [testString];
}

class State1 extends TestState {
  State1({required String testString}) : super(testString);
}
```

`Events`

```
abstract class TestEvent {}

class ChangeStringToSaved extends TestEvent {}

class UpdateSaved extends TestEvent {}
```

`HydradedBloc`

```
class TestBloc extends HydratedBloc<TestEvent, TestState> {
  TestBloc() : super(State1(testString: 'not saved')) {
    on<ChangeStringToSaved>(
        (event, emit) => emit(State1(testString: 'this is saved')));
    on<UpdateSaved>(
        (event, emit) => emit(State1(testString: 'updated saved value')));
  }
// Creating State1 from stored Map
  @override
  TestState? fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
    return State1(testString: json['value'] as String);
  }
// Saving to a basic Map
  @override
  Map<String, dynamic>? toJson(TestState state) {
    return {'value': state.testString};
  }
}
```

Basic UI

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            BlocConsumer<TestBloc, TestState>(
                listener: (context, state) {},
                builder: (context, state) {
                  return Text(state.testString);
                }),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () =>
                  context.read<TestBloc>().add(ChangeStringToSaved()),
              child: Text('Change to Saved'),
            ),
            ElevatedButton(
              onPressed: () => context.read<TestBloc>().add(UpdateSaved()),
              child: Text('Update Saved'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Anytime I update the `testString`, its automatically persisted after a restart.

So if I understand correctly you're looking for a full on database in addition to just being able to restart in whatever previous state you were in.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I updated my question to show some code. This helped me get closer, but now I am not sure how to get more than one value from the storage.

Comment: That answered my question. Thank you very much!